# Heroku w/ sqlite3 issues: Precompiling assets failed. Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, push

So, I cam across a error when pushing to heroku that I have not seen before. I am actively trying learn what the error means so I can fix it.

I see there there is issues with my sqlite3 but still cannot figure out a fix. After screwing up my gem files and then hours to get it back working on my local, I am here to ask for some help.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
Haydens-MacBook-Air:TicketFee_Calculator haydengoldman$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 215, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (197/197), done.
Writing objects: 100% (215/215), 291.41 KiB | 244.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 215 (delta 66), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.3
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Using json 1.8.1
       Installing minitest 5.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.6.11
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Installing mime-types 2.4.1
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Installing rdoc 4.1.2
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.1
       Installing mail 2.6.1
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing sprockets 2.11.0
       Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing uglifier 2.5.3
       Installing activesupport 4.1.6
       Installing activemodel 4.1.6
       Installing jbuilder 2.2.2
       Installing actionview 4.1.6
       Installing actionpack 4.1.6
       Installing railties 4.1.6
       Installing actionmailer 4.1.6
       Installing activerecord 4.1.6
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.4
       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.2
       Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
       Installing turbolinks 2.4.0
       Installing rails 4.1.6
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (22.97s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: Paths in SQLite3 database URLs of the form `sqlite3:///path` will be treated as absolute in Rails 4.2. Please switch to `sqlite3:dbname`. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/Rakefile:6)
       rake aborted!
       Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `rescue in spec'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:187:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:252:in `block in replace_gem'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_4336c1c2-aef4-47f5-a267-de3bc5fa5690/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:ancient-castle-6465.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:ancient-castle-6465.git'
```

Comment: `Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'sqlite3' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).` Looks like a good tip, do you have `gem 'sqlite3'` in your gemfile?

Comment: I do have the sqlite 3 gem. One reason why I am so confused. This will get resolved, just gonna take some head scratching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku uses postgresql database, so remove the **sqlite3** from the gem file or move it to the development group and add the **gem 'pg'** to your gem file. Regarding **database.yml** setting follow this [Heroku setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#running-rails-on-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have removed the sqlite3 gem from your Gemfile and ran `bundle install`. 
If you continue to receive this error, check your Gemfile.lock as some gems list sqlite3 as a dependency - you'll want to remove those gems as well.